# KVM monitoring without agents

Tags: monitoring, virtualization, kvm

I have a host with KVM guests and I want to monitor these guest (like Nagios).
However I doesn't want to install an agent on the virtual machines.
In fact I want to monitor the VM since the host

Is it possible to get the same information ?

Thanks in your advance for your help

John S

Answer (score 1):

On host side you can monitor presense of hypervisor process (it may likely provide some information about guest state/health). It cannot provide info on you guest OS or app running inside guest so you likely need some agent inside guest to get meaningful information. Perhaps for nagios SNMP server inside guest is the easiest approach.

So the answer depends on what exactly you mean by "monitoring the guest".